# SilverStripe 3.5 - GET form that respects already set url parameters

Tags: silverstripe

I've got three forms on my page that filter and sort a view of dataobjects.

The problem is after submitting one form, the url parametes set by another form a lost due to the FormAction wich redirects back to the current url without keeping the query string. Is there a way to combine those?

So if my url looks like `domaint.tld?color=blue&size=l` and after I used the sort form the new parameters would just applied to the current url like `domaint.tld?color=blue&size=l&sort=TitleASC` instead of removing the already set parameters?

The important part of my code looks like that

```
return $form
  ->setFormMethod('GET')
  ->setFormAction($this->Link() . '#produkte') // todo: join links?!
  ->disableSecurityToken()
  ->loadDataFrom($this->request->getVars());
```

I've already tried to replace `$this->Link`with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but that's the new request. Even hard coding the link with the before set parameters (just for testing purpose) replaces the link without respecting the set parameters.

Comment: Why not save the state of these forms to the Session?

Comment: that's my workaround for now. but i'd like to have a link you could share

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're mostly there already. There is the question to be had though before I answer - I'm unsure if submitting a GET method  will override all existing query parameters, or if they will be appended/overwritten as necessary. This is not to do with SilverStripe though, but it is worth mentioning in case it's a blocker to your implementation's design (in the case of overwrite). It may depend on user agent. It's not something I've considered before.

A form method as you probably know is a method to return a Form object, and is where a form will submit itself by default. This means that during fabrication in it's factory, GET parameters are ignored (the default value is basically `$controller->Link($factory_name)`). So when you use `setFormAction` you need to also take the query string into account at this point. You could use `Controller::join_links` as you've hinted at, or build the string yourself, it doesn't particularly matter I think, so long as the resulting `action=` attribute on the `<form>` reflects this correctly.

The second thing you'll need to take into account, is the `FormAction`. This is completely user defined, and using `Controller::redirectBack` simply rebuilds the route - it does not use the request (AFAIK). Again you'll need to take the full `$request->getVars` into account at this point, as above. Beyond that, it should be smooth sailing... without considering this posts opening caveat.

Comment: that's what I also know until now ;) but I couldn't figure out an working example. can you?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `$this->Link()` and add all important get-vars to it. `Controller::join_links()` is a good helper. E.g. `Controller::join_links('?foo=1', '?bar=2')` will result in `?foo=1&bar=2`.

I once had a similar problem and [wrote about it](http://www.silverstrip.es/blog/filter-used-get-parameters-and-pass-them-to-the-current-link/).

In your controller you can overwrite the `Link()` method to get all your params:

```
public function Link($action = '')
{
    $base = parent::Link($action);

    foreach(['foo', 'bar'] as $getParam) {
            if ($this->request->getVar($getParam)) {
                $additionalParams[] =  $getParam . '=' . $this->request->getVar($getParam);
        }
        }

        return Controller::join_links($base, '?' . join('&',    $additionalParams));
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build the query. Less code to write and not as ugly as string concatenations…